# Parameter object becomes null after being passed to function

Tags: c#, list, function

I'm new to c#. I'm trying to send a list item as a parameter of a function. Before the moment it is passed the item exists. But inside the function it appears to be null. I would be grateful if anyone could explain me my mistake.

```
    List<HSCodeData> HSCodeDataList;

    internal void buildHSCodeDocument(List<HSCodeData> initHSCodeDataList)
    {
        HSCodeDataList = initHSCodeDataList;           

        foreach (HSCodeData dataItem in HSCodeDataList)
        {
            if ((dataItem != null)&&(dataItem.HSCode!=""))
            {
                string descriptionString = BuildDescriptionString(dataItem);
                dataItem.ParentHSCode = descriptionString;
            }                 
        }
    }

    internal string BuildDescriptionString(HSCodeData HSCodeDataItem)
    {
        string descriptionString = HSCodeDataItem.Description + ItemSuggestedDescription(HSCodeDataItem);
        if ((ItemHasParent(HSCodeDataItem.ParentHSCode)) && (HSCodeDataList != null) && (HSCodeDataList.Count != 0))
        {
            descriptionString += BuildDescriptionString(findParentItem(HSCodeDataItem.ParentHSCode));
        }
        return descriptionString;
    }
```

Comment: post the code from where you call this method

Comment: string descriptionString = BuildDescriptionString(dataItem);
this is the code

and inside the BuildDescriptionString function the dataItem is null

Comment: I actually check that the item is not null before sending it as a parameter but I guess that I'm doing something wrong with using either the foreach statement or maybe a list.

Comment: Can you please post the whole snippet, including the calling function?

Comment: I meant `buildHSCodeDocument(List<HSCodeData>)` ...  debug the code where you adding *null* objects to `List<HSCodeData>`,

Comment: So is the parameter `initHSCodeDataList` null, or the list item `dataItem` is null? An object list can contain null values

Comment: No it actually contains more than 7000 non null items.
And before calling the BuildDescriptionString(dataItem) method I check this item for not being null. So this looks really weird for me.

Comment: Show the `BuildDescriptionString` method

Comment: And on which exact line do you get the null exception?

Comment: string descriptionString = HSCodeDataItem.Description + ItemSuggestedDescription(HSCodeDataItem);

Comment: And now the `ItemSuggestedDescription` please

Comment: I've even commented out the ItemSuggestedDescription so it is not the reason
The reason is that HSCodeDataItem appears to be null
Though it used to a be a non null object before

Comment: My guess: `findParentItem` returns `null` and you get the NRE in the recursive call to `BuildDescriptionString`.

Comment: Yes. I guess that this is the reason. Could you please write it as an answer for me to vote for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `buildHSCodeDocument` there is no way the argument passed to `BuildDescriptionString` could be `null`. But there is a recursive call to `BuildDescriptionString` where the return value of `findParentItem` is passed.
Probably `findParentItem` returns `null`.